# The type or namespace name 'BasicSteps' does not exist in the namespace 'OpenTap.Plugins'

Tags: c#, opentap-proj

I am trying to build BuildTestPlan.Api in the Solution 'Examples' of the OpenTap SDK.
However, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'BasicSteps' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'OpenTap.Plugins' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Apparently, the project includes a dependency OpenTap.Plugins.BasicSteps. However, I can't find a dll of this dependence.

I recently reinstalled my OpenTap version from 9.4.1 to the latest one (9.5.1), via the 'download button' on the OpenTap.io website.

Comment: This would seems to be a problem to be reported on the project page of OpenTap it self. Your solution is not really suited for somebody else who wants to use this project. You didnn't really fix it, you just made your build work. A better solution would be to report this issue and submit your solution as a pull request there. Then the maintainers of the project can validate your solution!

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 Thanks for your comment. A guideline of the OpenTap project is to ask questions on StackOverflow. I.e. issues containing only questions should be redirected to SO. I was thinking of my problem more as a question than an issue. I think my 'workaround' isn't suited for making a pull request. I'm going to submit an issue with my suggested workaround included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the SDK package in earlier OpenTAP versions. This issue has been resolved in the latest release, OpenTAP v9.7.0. It's available at [opentap.io](http://www.opentap.io).

Answer (score 1):

I looked a bit at the repo itself out of interest who they do it.  I have no previous experience with Gitlab CI builds.

It would seem all package references for their internal packages are references with a version specifier to be calculated at build time. 
But you need to run the correct commands for this.
Take a look at the contents of the build script .gitlab-ci.yml in the section Package-SDK.
[How to  gitlab ci build](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/README.html)

Here we see that the csproj files are copied to a build folder and transformed with the coorect version number of the nuget package to be used. ( via gitversion?)

This would mean that in our case the correct references would be used.

But as far as I can understand the intention of the package, you as consumer should not use the repo directly to test the examples, but use the TapPackage for the SDK:
[TapPackages listing](https://www.opentap.io/packages.html)

Apparantly this is a packaging method specific for them, but it's just a zip file you can download, unzip and build the code.

Comment: After all this, there is still the bug of the reference :(.  It would seem the reference hint path also needs the same transform. But today I don't see the same nuget package as the version proposed in the TapPackage -->  difference in versioning between TapPackage and nuget packages?  Very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed to make my build work. The used OS is Windows 10.

- Download OpenTap, or execute

> git clone https://gitlab.com/OpenTAP/opentap.git

- Use Visual Studio 2017 or later. This package needs to be installed:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321
- Open OpenTAP.sln, build the solution.
- Under ../opentap/bin/Debug, note that there are the files OpenTap.dll and also OpenTap.Plugins.BasicSteps.dll. We will have to add the BasicSteps dll again to our project.
- Open the solution ../opentap/sdk/Examples/Examples.sln
- Select the project ExamplePlugin as StartUp project
- Under the project TestPlanExecution, there is a problem with the OpenTap.Plugins.BasicSteps dependency. Remove this dependency.
- Add the reference again, from ../opentap/bin/Debug/
- Building the solution should succeed now.
- In ../opentap/sdk/Examples/bin/Debug, you can find Editor.exe. Using this, you can try out all the examples.